# Guide to starting my own Tier-3 ISP service in Pakistan?

Tags: isp, service-provider

I'm new to networking. I'm based in Karachi, Pakistan and am a game and simulations developer by profession (Unreal 4 lyf fk Unity).

When I came back here from the UK, I witnessed absolute shit service and even shittier "holier-than-thou" attitudes from these local ISPs who think knowing how to splice a fiber cable suddenly makes them superior and any and all complaints from their customers can be solved by telling them to fuck off and reboot their router.

So given Pakistan's abysmal currency value and my bank accounts being in USD, I figured, with enough knowledge and a couple network engineers hired, I could probably launch a Tier-3 ISP myself if these school-failed idiots can do it.

Please educate me.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here. It is too broad and will attract off-topic opinion-based answers. The subject is very large, and a proper answer cannot be entered here. We can answer specific questions with specific answers, but such an open-ended question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Ron, could you suggest corrections to my question for a more precise answer?

Comment: If you're going to close a question, atleast suggest corrections so I can repost and get an answer. I don't come onto these forums often so I am not accustomed to questions are written here

Comment: @RazaZaidi Ron did point out how you can improve your question - see [ask] for more details.